# EL Problems with deployment on glassfish

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, deployment, glassfish

I'm having a hard time trying to deploy a webapp (actually working on tomcat) onto glasssfish 3.

I tried different solutions, but none actually worked. I keep getting a:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
```

I tried to set the following in my web.xml:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

without any luck...

I removed all the jsp / jstl / el-api / el-impl... jars which were there in the first place, but it keeps failing.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was with tiles. I had versions conflicts with spring 2 and tiles 2.2x.